# self recursive function type in rust

Tags: rust

just curiosity: In python

```py
def f(x):
    print(x)
    return f
```

but I can't figure out how to write it in rust.

```rs
fn f(x:i32) -> ?{
    println!("{}", x);
    ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it with just an `fn` item.

Both `fn f(x: i32) -> fn() -> ...` and `fn f(x: i32) -> impl Fn() -> ...` aren't useful here, because you can't name the return type of the return type.

Trying to define a type alias `type F = fn(i32) -> F` also doesn't solve the problem, as it leads to a cycle error, and you can't use `Self` in type aliases.

I believe the only way is to use nightly-only features to implement the `Fn` trait of families for a struct, thus being able to name it when implementing `Fn`:

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

struct F;

impl FnOnce<(i32,)> for F {
    type Output = F;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (i32,)) -> Self::Output {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl FnMut<(i32,)> for F {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (i32,)) -> Self::Output {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl Fn<(i32,)> for F {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (x,): (i32,)) -> Self::Output {
        println!("{}", x);
        Self
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb07908dc9633eb9511db2768d6cc984)

Downside with this problem is that you can't really get a `fn(i32) -> Self`, only a `fn(i32) -> F`, and you can't make `F` "implement" `fn(i32) -> F`, as it's not a trait.

**All this said, this is probably a bad idea and only really useful for curiosity's sake**